# How to auto reply of a Gmail emails

Tags: zapier

Here am using gmail and streak with zapier. And my problem is as:
How can I automatically reply to the incoming emails using zapier.

when anyone send me any email my current configuration send a thanks mail to that sender but to it reply.
Here I want to reply on all emails automatically.
Please help me soon.

Comment: Hi Amit and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please explain a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish? It is unclear what do you want than you don't have already...

Comment: I am using Streak CRM. My requirement is that when any one send me a email to my email Id. then a box should be created in my streak pipeline an with email subject and A thank should be reply to that sender instantly.    How can I do it Using Zapier

Comment: please help me.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. I haven't used Streak CRM before, but it sounds like you want to send an email every time a new box is created? If so, the following template will do just that:

https://zapier.com/apps/gmail/integrations/streak/3574/get-gmail-emails-from-new-boxes-in-streak